# How to determine where an Angular route redirect originates?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

I have an Angular 6 SPA.  Periodically, the app performs an action behind the scenes in an iframe (to silently refresh an OAuth token).  Each time my app does this, it redirects to the "/" route.  This is undesirable behavior for the reason that if a user is in the middle of completing a form, he will lose his form and be redirected.

I believe that the redirect is happening as a result of something in my code; perhaps a Guard.  Is there good a way to determine the source of a route redirect in Angular?

Answer (score 2):

You can enable debug mode for rouuting in angular using enableTracing

```js
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })
```

You will see there is a lot of event running in the app when using routing. So you can do debug more easily. Hope that help.

[image]